# Donut tutorial: Condensation for coffee cup not adding

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I'm doing the donut tutorial. I'm on Part 5, Level 3: Condensation. At 18 minutes Andrew adds a condensation tuxture. I've added a material and the faces I select can change color and I assigned it. I've watched and retried this 5 times, but the texture will not add to the cup. My nodes are exactly like his. A download link to my project is below. Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6770" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6770/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your file, it works fine after I relinked the image from my local drive. Maybe the image link is broken? Did you assign the material in Edit Mode? there is my screenshot of all the windows.

[image]

Comment: I did assign the material in edit mode, but I'll check again later. Guess I can also try relinking.  At least I know I'm on the right path now. If I get it, I'll update. Thanks.

Comment: I made sure my material was assigned. It was. I'm able to edit the material base color in the principled BSDF node. I tried relinking, but it was already linked. I also tried removing my image from the image node and readding it. Nothing shows.

Comment: Have you checked the UV? If the image is linked, the preview under material should be showing up, like the one on my image.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the *Shading* tab and <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Click</kbd> on *Principled BSDF* node

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: First, I posted this 17 months ago. Second, this doesn't answer the question